# Azure media streaming locators expiry

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Are expired streaming locators in azure still counted towards the 100 limit? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/limits-quotas-constraints#packaging--delivery-limits.

Meaning, do I need to be actively cleaning expired streaming locators so as to not reach this limit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Media Services Locators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658650/azure-media-services-locators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put some logic in to check the the expiry dates of the ILocator and then delete it.

You can call [`ILocator.ExpirationDateTime.ToUniversalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mediaservices.client.ilocator.expirationdatetime?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MediaServices_Client_ILocator_ExpirationDateTime) to find the date/time that it will or did expire.

When a locator is expired you need to delete if it you are at the 100 locator limit before you can add a new one. You can also call [`ILocator.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.mediaservices.client.ilocator.update?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_MediaServices_Client_ILocator_Update_System_DateTime_)(DateTime newExpiryTime)

For more details, you can refer [David's answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658650/azure-media-services-locators).

Comment: Thanks. Follow up question though, do you know if a locator is expired and the expiration date is updated, do any streaming Urls made from that locator gain new life?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, expired streaming locators count towards the 100 locators per asset limit so you will need to actively clean the expired ones up if you are at risk of hitting this limit.